# ProGuard fails after update Google Play Services to version 5.0 (revision 18)

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard, android-support-library

My Ant script for compiling my Android app worked fine, but after updating the Google Play Services library to version 5.0 (revision 18) ProGuard fails with the following output:

```
-obfuscate:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /srv2/jenkins/jobs/CCNF Google only/workspace/trunk/org.digitalcure.ccnf.app/bin/proguard
      [jar] Building jar: /srv2/jenkins/jobs/CCNF Google only/workspace/trunk/org.digitalcure.ccnf.app/bin/proguard/original.jar
 [proguard] ProGuard, version 4.7
 [proguard] Reading input...
 [proguard] Reading program jar [/srv2/jenkins/jobs/CCNF Google only/workspace/trunk/org.digitalcure.ccnf.app/bin/proguard/original.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [/srv2/jenkins/jobs/CCNF Google only/workspace/trunk/org.digitalcure.android.common/bin/classes.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [/srv2/jenkins/jobs/CCNF Google only/workspace/trunk/google-play-services_lib/bin/classes.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [/srv2/jenkins/jobs/CCNF Google only/workspace/trunk/android-support-v7-appcompat/bin/classes.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [/srv2/jenkins/jobs/CCNF Google only/workspace/trunk/android-support-v7-appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [/srv2/jenkins/jobs/CCNF Google only/workspace/trunk/android-support-v7-appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar]
 [proguard] Reading program jar [/srv2/jenkins/jobs/CCNF Google only/workspace/trunk/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [/srv/jenkins/tools/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-17/android.jar]
 [proguard] Initializing...
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
 [proguard] Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find dynamically referenced class android.app.Notification$Action
 [proguard] Note: android.support.v4.text.ICUCompatIcs: can't find dynamically referenced class libcore.icu.ICU
 [proguard] Note: com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImplGmm6
 [proguard] Note: com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl
 [proguard] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'Object'
 [proguard]       Maybe you meant the fully qualified name 'java.lang.Object'?
 [proguard] Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.ads.AdSize { AdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter { com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest a(android.content.Context,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest,android.os.Bundle,android.os.Bundle); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter { void requestBannerAd(android.content.Context,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationBannerListener,android.os.Bundle,com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest,android.os.Bundle); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationBannerListener'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter { void requestBannerAd(android.content.Context,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationBannerListener,android.os.Bundle,com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest,android.os.Bundle); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter { void requestBannerAd(android.content.Context,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationBannerListener,android.os.Bundle,com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest,android.os.Bundle); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter { void requestInterstitialAd(android.content.Context,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialListener,android.os.Bundle,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest,android.os.Bundle); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialListener'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter { void requestInterstitialAd(android.content.Context,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialListener,android.os.Bundle,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest,android.os.Bundle); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter$a { AdMobAdapter$a(com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationBannerListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationBannerListener'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter$b { AdMobAdapter$b(com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialListener'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventAdapter { void requestBannerAd(com.google.ads.mediation.MediationBannerListener,android.app.Activity,com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventServerParameters,com.google.ads.AdSize,com.google.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventExtras); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventExtras'
 [proguard] Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventAdapter { void requestInterstitialAd(com.google.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialListener,android.app.Activity,com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventServerParameters,com.google.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventExtras); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.customevent.CustomEventExtras'
 [proguard] Note: there were 4 references to unknown classes.
 [proguard]       You should check your configuration for typos.
 [proguard] Note: there were 11 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
 [proguard]       You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
 [proguard]       (using '-keep').
 [proguard] Note: there were 5 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
 [proguard]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
 [proguard] Warning: there were 9 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
 [proguard]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
```

Comparing it with the former (working) output, the following lines are new:

```
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
 [proguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
 [proguard] Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find dynamically referenced class android.app.Notification$Action
```

plus the error message at the end of the output.

What happened? It seams that android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager was introduced with API level 19.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I noticed that the target version of the Android support library changed from 16 to 19 (updated it at the same time to revision 20). My app was build against target version 17. So I changed the target version of the main app project from 17 to 19 and everything is fine now. That's it!

Comment: Thanks - this solved the issue for me. This may be obvious to some, but just to be really clear: It's in the Android section of the Project Settings where you need to change the target version to >=19. Initially I was just dumb enough to think changing the target SDK version in the manifest from 17 to 19 was sufficient, which of course it isn't.

Answer (score 4):

For people who @stefan222 's answer did not work you can add

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.cast.**
```

to your proguard.cfg

do this at your own risk though. Make sure that you test your app thoroughly if you do add that.

Answer (score 0):

For People who want to get rid of the warnings:

so no warnings will be shown at all

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```